# Highlighted Current date cell in Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I tried to Highlight the current date cell in SharePoint Calendar via OOB feature, but didn't find any!!

Is it possible via OOB ?  or via some code?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can do it with .has. SharePoint will label the out of the box calendar's current date with the div class 'ms-acal-today', so just look for a child that has that. Alternatively, .find.